# Using signtool without Windows SDK?

Tags: windows-10, code-signing, signtool

Can I use signtool on Windows 10 without the Windows SDK (2.5 GB) installed? Can I just copy the signtool.exe from a different machine?

I am building a cross platform application for Windows inside a VM which resides on my pretty small SSD, thus I don't want to blow it with unnecessary software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, sometimes one should just give it a try instead of asking questions ;-) If anyone stumbles upon this:

Yes, one can just copy the small `signtool.exe` from a different machine (under Win 10 usually located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\`) to your path (e.g. `C:\Windows\`).

No additional libraries are needed.

Comment: That is not working for me... the signtool.exe has dependencies such as wintrust.dll and mssign32.dll and could be others...

Comment: I added some code that add all dependencies...however, it works fine in my Win10 machine (that has several VS and ,NET FW and SDKs...) However, same code does not work in other non dev machines (Not sure what is missing in those machines)